# I want to compare all cells of sheet 1 to sheet 2 and matched values turn yellow

Tags: excel

I want to compare all cells of sheet 1 to sheet 2 and matched values turn yellow, following code i used,

```
 Sub match()
    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    strRangeToCheck = "A1:IV65536"
    varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    Debug.Print Now
    For icell = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)

    If varSheetA(icell) = varSheetB(icell) Then
    cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow

     `enter code here` End If
    Next icell

   End Sub
```

Comment: can someone answer plzzzzzzzz.?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub match()
    Dim shtA As Worksheet
    Dim shtB As Worksheet
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim cA as range, cB as range

    strRangeToCheck = "A1:IV65536"
    set shtA = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    set shtB = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Debug.Print Now

    For Each cA IN shtA.Range(strRangeToCheck)
        on error resume next
        if cA.value <> "" then
            Set cB = shtB.Range(strRangeToCheck).find(what:=cA.value, lookin:=xlvalues, lookat:=xlwhole)
            If Not cB is Nothing then
                cA.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        end if
        on error goto 0
    Next cA
End Sub
```

Comment: It turns yellow to empty cells only.Can you correct it plz?

Comment: there must be something wrong, let IF statement (`If c.value = shtB.Range(c.address).value Then`) make the decision out of our expect.

Comment: I rewrite my answer with `.Find` method.